# pivotting mysql output 90 degrees

Tags: mysql

I have been writing a query that returns the number of male friends living in a given country, and then all the female friends of the user.

The table i am using looks like this: [image]

```
    SELECT COUNT(gender)
FROM (SELECT friend.*
FROM friendship
JOIN user_profile AS friend ON friend.id = friendship.user_profile2_id
JOIN location ON friend.location_id = location.id
WHERE friendship.user_profile1_id = :userId AND location.current_country = "Israel"
UNION
SELECT friend.*
FROM friendship
JOIN user_profile AS friend ON friend.id = friendship.user_profile1_id
JOIN location ON friend.locationId = location.id
WHERE friendship.user_profile2_id = :userId AND location.current_country = "Israel") AS friends
GROUP BY gender
```

output should be 2 numbers,

25

20

I am trying to pivot the output so it is two columns instead

25  20

I came up with a convoluted solution that I know can be improved

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT * FROM friendship
  JOIN user_profile AS friend ON friend.id = friendship.user_profile_two.id
  JOIN location ON friend.locationId = location.id
  WHERE friendship.user_profile1_id = :userId AND friend.gender = "Male" AND location.current_country = "Israel"
  UNION
  SELECT friend.*
  FROM friendship
  JOIN user_profile AS friend ON friend.id = friendship.user_profile_one.id
  JOIN location ON friend.locationId = location.id
  WHERE friendship.user_profile2_id = :userId AND friend.gender = "Male" AND location.current_country = "Israel")) AS male_friends,

  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT * FROM friendship
  JOIN user_profile AS friend ON friend.id = friendship.user_profile_two.id
  JOIN location ON friend.locationId = location.id
  WHERE friendship.user_profile1_id = :userId AND friend.gender = "Female" AND location.current_country = "Israel"
  UNION
  SELECT friend.*
  FROM friendship
  JOIN user_profile AS friend ON friend.id = friendship.user_profile_one.id
  JOIN location ON friend.locationId = location.id
  WHERE friendship.user_profile2_id = :userId AND friend.gender = "Female" AND location.current_country = "Israel")) AS female_friends
FROM friendship
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Just rotate your monitor. Failing that, consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Comment: like @Strawberry said this is mostly likely better to be handeld in the application code.  *"rotating mysql output 90 degrees"* But the correct terms would be [pivotting](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+pivot) or [convert records into columns](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+convert+record+into+columns) .. this question is a duplicate of existing questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: Also, is it deliberate that you won't know which gender is which?

Comment: Also, is it deliberate that there should be only two genders?

Comment: Spencer's so woke.